# Will using a Function to simplify SQL Query massively imapact performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, function

I have a query which uses a complicated set of CASE statements, some nested, some with a COALESCE of CASE statements, and it is a pain to manage.

The same basic logic applies to around 12 columns in the SELECT, and could be modularised and placed in a function - with benefits including consistency and ease of prototyping.

***Will putting the logic into a function massively impede performance?*** Are functions inherently slower?

The SELECT Pulls from 5 tables each of around 100,000 rows, so performance is of some importance.

SQL Server 2005

Comment: why don't you try and benchmark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, *selecting* a result of a scalar function won't hurt much, but *filtering* by it may easily cost hundreds of seconds (not necessarily though).

If you need to filter by a scalar function result (`WHERE col = dbo.scalar_function()`), it often helps to make an inline table-valued function instead. It would return its value as the only row of the result table. You would then do `inner join` with the function result, effectively filtering by the returned value. This works because SQL Server is always able to unwind inline table-valued functions and inline them into the calling query.

Note this trick won't work if the function is a multi-step one. These cannot be unwound.

Comment: Thankfully there won't be any filtering by cunction, but that is a helpful answer. I will read up on the table valued stuff if I can find anything interesting. Cheers!