# Is CTE's performance better than (UDF) user-defined function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName
FROM Sales.Customer c
WHERE Sales.ufnGetLastOrderDate(c.CustomerId) < DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
```

The `Sales.ufnGetLastOrderDate` user-defined function (UDF) is defined as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sales.ufnGetLastOrderDate(@CustomerID int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @lastOrderDate datetime

   SELECT @lastOrderDate = MAX(OrderDate)
   FROM Sales.SalesOrder
   WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

   RETURN @lastOrderDate
END
```

Now I want to improve the performance of the query. The answer is to drop the UDF and rewrite the report query as follows:

```
WITH cte(CustomerID, LastOrderDate) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CustomerID, MAX(OrderDate) AS [LastOrderDate]
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesOrder
    GROUP BY 
        CustomerID
)
SELECT c.CustomerName
FROM cte
INNER JOIN Sales.Customer c ON cte.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE cte.LastOrderDate < DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
```

My question is why the query has a better performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will using a Function to simplify SQL Query massively imapact performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008252/will-using-a-function-to-simplify-sql-query-massively-imapact-performance)

Comment: Run them both and see which is better?

Comment: @JacobH, I have not data for the query. It's an exam problem.

Comment: You are posting questions on an online forum to get answers to your exam???

Comment: Not my exam. I am not student. It is a simulation exam for improving skills..

Comment: Scalar functions are horrible for performance. As such in the example posted the one with the scalar function is going to suck from a performance standpoint. I would at least consider converting that to an inline table valued function and it should be just as fast as the cte but has the benefit of being reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE is essentially a view. 
So in your example, with a CTE, is converted into

```
SELECT c.CustomerName
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderDate) AS [LastOrderDate]
      FROM Sales.SalesOrder
     GROUP BY CustomerID) cte
  INNER JOIN Sales.Customer c ON cte.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE cte.LastOrderDate < DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
```

where the query inside the () is first executed and the cte.CustomerID join is performed as a batch, where as the scalar function, is executed multiple times, once for each CustomerID.