# Create a Function in SQL Server that return many values to use for sort

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has a customized sort (after `order by`). In other words, after `order by` I do some substring and length calculations on some fields and sort on two criteria:

```
    Order By 
 LEFT(InvoiceID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', InvoiceID) - 1), --first sort value
 CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(InvoiceID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', InvoiceID), LEN(InvoiceID))) -- second sort value
```

The problem is that I need to use the same sort on many other stored procedures. So I want to create a function that applies the same sort. While I can make a function that returns one value, I need a function that returns two values as above.

This sql function does not work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_AlphaNumreicSort] (@AlphaNumreicValue nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS (
@SortedVar1  nvarchar(MAX)
,@SortedVar2  nvarchar(MAX)
)
AS
....
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return more than one value, you need to declare a table valued function.
In your case you can make an inline function too, which has the added benefit of it working much faster, as if it was a [part of the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8008371/11683).

```
create function [dbo].[fn_AlphaNumreicSort] (@AlphaNumreicValue nvarchar(MAX))
returns table
as
return (
  select
    LEFT(@AlphaNumreicValue, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumreicValue) - 1) as SortedVar1,
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@AlphaNumreicValue, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @AlphaNumreicValue), LEN(@AlphaNumreicValue))) as SortedVar2
);
```

You then use it in the query with `outer apply`:

```
select ...
from
  some_table
  outer apply [dbo].[fn_AlphaNumreicSort](InvoiceID) as sort_values
...
order by
  sort_values.SortVar1,
  sort_values.SortVar2
```

Comment: Thank you @GSerg; Is there any way we can handle this without the outer apply? I mean by call function only after order by?

Comment: @BasharAbuShamaa That does not make sense, you cannot call anything "after order by". You were not calling your original expressions "after order by" either, the server would calculate them before ordering. If you are worried that this function will be called for more rows than ultimately go into the resultset, then don't worry and let the server do its job.